# pyinstaller does not create working executable when using multiprocess module in linux

Tags: linux, pyinstaller, multiprocess

I created the small sample to demonstrate error I'm seeing trying to use pyinstaller to build an executable program. My python is 3.6.5 and is installed /home/repos/ges/Python/bin. I was not sure if the non-standard python install is playing contributing role in error.

```
import time
import random
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool


# A function to run against a list
def this_job(job):

time_delay = random.randrange(0, 5)
time.sleep(time_delay)

print("after a small " + str(time_delay) + " second delay here is job " + str(job))


forked_jobs = []
for i in range(500):
    forked_jobs.append(i)


# Make the Pool of workers and do the work
pool = ThreadPool(10)
pool.map(this_job, forked_jobs)
# close the pool and wait for the work to finish
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I can run the file from where I wrote it and see output similar to:

after a small 0 second delay here is job 52

after a small 0 second delay here is job 117

after a small 1 second delay here is job 39

after a small 1 second delay here is job 65...

When I try to build this using ./python3 pyinstaller bp2.py and run the executable in the dist folder I see the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/rthooks/pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py", line 8, in 
  File "/home/repos/ges/Python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
  File "multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 19, in 
    from . import util
  File "/home/repos/ges/Python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
  File "multiprocessing/util.py", line 17, in 
    from subprocess import _args_from_interpreter_flags
  File "/home/repos/ges/Python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
  File "subprocess.py", line 136, in 
  File "/home/repos/ges/Python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
ImportError: /home/repos/ges/Python/GES_Module/dist/bp2/_posixsubprocess.so: undefined symbol: _Py_set_inheritable_async_safe
[15670] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_multiprocessing

Not sure how to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I was getting this error as a result of my python build location. I tested the above on a machine with python installed in a typical location and it works as expected.